# Getting value of another tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

In the below code `onclick` edit how can the value of tag test be obtained in the edit function:

```
<script>
function edit(a) 
{

} 
var a=     <tr class="clickable"><td id="userval" BGCOLOR="#FF6699"><label id="test">' + a + '</lable>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <IMG SRC="edit.gif" onclick="javascript:edit(test.value);" > ></td></tr>
</script>
```

Comment: This code is syntactically invalid. What is `a` supposed to be set to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming jQuery usage:

```
<script>
function edit(elem) 
{
   $(elem).siblings('label#test').html();
} 

var a= '<tr class="clickable"><td id="userval" BGCOLOR="#FF6699"><label id="test">' + a + '</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <IMG SRC="edit.gif" onclick="javascript:edit(this);" > ></td></tr>
</script>
```

Comment: and how to set this to some other value?

Answer (score 1):

I take it `a` is actually a string? (it's not in your example, but it's concatenated as though it were)

```
function edit(a) 
{
    var value = $(a).find('#test').text();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var value = $("#test", $(a)).text()
```